# The supplied API key is not configured for use from this Android app in Google map Road Api(speed limit)

Tags: android, google-roads-api

The supplied `API` key is not configured for use from this Android app in **Google** `map` Road Api

1. Created `API` key with SHA1 & package name from `API` console(Premium account)
2. Enabled road API
3. My `API` key is showing google map but getting below exception
4. com.google.maps.errors.RequestDeniedException: The supplied API key is not configured for use from this Android app.

Comment: share more information about it.

Comment: My API key is showing google map but getting below exception

com.google.maps.errors.RequestDeniedException: The supplied API key is not configured for use from this Android app.

Comment: share your code.

Comment: Did you find out the reason? I'm dealing with the same thing.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428813/the-supplied-api-key-is-not-configured-for-use-from-this-android-app-in-google-m